# Запуск exe файла из Mono на сервере

Tags: c#, linux, mono

Добрый день!

Допустим, я под Дебианом с графической средой в Mono соберу свой проект как консольный, а после захочу его запустить на сервере под управлением всё того же Дебиана. Какие пакеты мне необходимо установить на сервере, чтобы иметь возможность запускать на нём exe файлы, собранные на другом линуксе, с помощью проекта моно?

РЕШЕНИЕ!!!

Как оказалось, для запуска необходимо установить пакет mono-complete, для того, чтобы всё работало (у меня, по крайней мере - простое серверное приложение). После разрешения всех зависимостей (достаточно много на голом **Debian 7.8**), команда

**mono ExeName.exe**

работает. Для установки пакета добавить репозитории, всё как указано в [документации по установки Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives):

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
apt-get update
```

Comment: либо тот же моно, либо виртуалбокс где поставить винду:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно посмотреть что за собой др приложения, которые на моно, тянут
например
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomboy_%28software%29
https://github.com/GNOME/tomboy

Comment: Спасибо, так и поступлю!